# Oracle-instantclient download using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I want to download oracle instant client in linux machine using automated shell script. Since its oracle site, we have to accept the license and then login to http://download.oracle.com, then do the download. But i need an shell script to automate this download than doing it manually.

I used the below command for this

```
wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/122010/oracle-
instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

But it says `401 Authorization Required`

[Error Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Zr9.png)

I tried java installation in similar way using below wget command it works fine. But the oracle instant client download is not working.

wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: Why do you trigger the download by shell script? Download it once and then distribute the downloaded file by shell script (I assume this is your actual intention)

Comment: Infact,  this is part of one automation script, hece it is not advisable to download manually and then copy the file to Linux server.

Comment: You can download it providing user and password as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget